# Usercontrol as datatemplate with bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, datatemplate

I have an ItemsControl with ItemsSource binded to a list of SystemModels. It has to generate an usercontrol for every system in the list. And in those usercontrols it has some textboxes that show the name, is and location of the system.

My code creates the usercontrols but doesn't fill the textboxes in the usercontrol.

View:

```
<UserControl x:Name="SystemListScreen">
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
                <ItemsControl x:Name="SystemList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Systems}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <UniformGrid Columns="4"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="SystemModel">
                        <Widgets:MultiLineButton partID="{Binding ID}"
                                                    company="{Binding ItemsSource.Company}"
                                                    typeSorter="{Binding ItemsSource.Name, ElementName=SystemList}"
                                                    typeLocation="{Binding ItemsSource.Location, ElementName=SystemList}"
                                                    buttonCommand="{Binding DataContext.navigateInspectList, ElementName=SystemListScreen}"
                                                    buttonCommandParameter="{Binding ItemsSource.ID, ElementName=SystemList}"/>
                        <!--<Button Content="{Binding ID}"/>-->
                    </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

ViewModel:

```
private List<SystemModel> systems;

public SystemListViewModel()
{
    Systems = new List<SystemModel>();
    Systems = SystemAPI.Instance.GetSystems();
}

public string App { get; set; }

public List<SystemModel> Systems 
{ 
    get { return systems; }
    private set 
    {
        systems = value;
        NotifyChanged("systems");
        NotifyChanged("NoResultsFound");
    } 
}
```

multilinebutton code:

```
        public static readonly DependencyProperty buttonCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("buttonCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MultiLineButton));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty buttonCommandParameterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("buttonCommandParameter", typeof(Object), typeof(MultiLineButton));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty partIDProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("partID", typeof(String), typeof(MultiLineButton));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty companyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("company", typeof(String), typeof(MultiLineButton));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty typeSorterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("typeSorter", typeof(String), typeof(MultiLineButton));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty typeLocationProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("typeLocation", typeof(String), typeof(MultiLineButton));

    public MultiLineButton()
    { 
        this.DataContext = this;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public String partID
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(partIDProperty); }
        set { SetValue(partIDProperty, value); }
    }

    public String company
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(companyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(companyProperty, value); }
    }

    public String typeSorter
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(typeSorterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(typeSorterProperty, value); }
    }

    public String typeLocation
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(typeLocationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(typeLocationProperty, value); }
    }

    public ICommand buttonCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(buttonCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(buttonCommandProperty, value); }
    }
    public Object buttonCommandParameter
    {
        get { return (Object)GetValue(buttonCommandParameterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(buttonCommandParameterProperty, value); }
    }
```

what not works: partID="{Binding ID}", company="{Binding ItemsSource.Company}", typeSorter="{Binding ItemsSource.Name, ElementName=SystemList}", typeLocation="{Binding ItemsSource.Location, ElementName=SystemList}" and buttonCommandParameter="{Binding ItemsSource.ID, ElementName=SystemList}".

But if i use just a button as datatemplate with Content="{Binding ID}" It works Perfect, an d if i use the usercontrol outside the datatemplate it works also. But it will not work inside the datatemplate.

The error i get is this: "BindingExpression path error: 'Company' property not found on 'object' ''MultiLineButton' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=Company; DataItem='MultiLineButton' (Name=''); target element is 'MultiLineButton' (Name=''); target property is 'company' (type 'String')"

How can i fix those bindings?

Comment: remove "ItemsSource." from Bindings. the dataContext has already been set to ItemsSource.

Comment: NotifyChanged("systems"); is case sensitive NotifyChanged("Systems")

Comment: thanks Bizz and Eran, but both doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

try ObservableCollection:

```
private ObservableCollection<SystemModel> _systems = new ObservableCollection<SystemModel>();
public ObservableCollection<SystemModel> Systems { get { return _systems; } }

public SystemListViewModel()
{
    var systems = SystemAPI.Instance.GetSystems();
    foreach (var system in systems)
    {
        Systems.Add(system);
    }
}
```

and xaml should be:

```
<UserControl x:Name="SystemListScreen">
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
                <ItemsControl x:Name="SystemList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Systems}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <UniformGrid Columns="4"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Widgets:MultiLineButton 
                                partID="{Binding ID}"
                                company="{Binding Company}"
                                typeSorter="{Binding Name}"
                                typeLocation="{Binding Location}"
                                buttonCommand="{Binding DataContext.navigateInspectList, 
                                    ElementName=SystemListScreen}"
                                buttonCommandParameter="{Binding ItemsSource.ID, 
                                    ElementName=SystemList}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

As chao wang said:

remove `DataType="SystemModel"` because if you're using just one type of DataType as DataTemplate it's not necessary. and the correct syntax is `DataType="vm:SystemModel"` where vm is defined in a parent tag like : `xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MySolution.MyVmProject.MyFolder"`

also, check these:

remove `ItemsSource.` from Bindings inside `DataTemplate` because it's just wrong.

double check all names in bindings because if they're wrong, a null value is considered during runtime and you never know.

check your dataContext make sure `UserControl` have its DataContext to the correct instance of type dependency object which has Systems in it. and make sure it remains that way.

Comment: try defining dependency property for ID, Company, Location and Name.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with defining dependency property? partID etc. are dependency propertys.

Comment: I thought you're using INotifyPropertyChanged with a normal object. It seems to me you're missing multiple things and that's because it's getting complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but its still not working. The error i get is this: "BindingExpression path error: 'Company' property not found on 'object' ''MultiLineButton' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=Company; DataItem='MultiLineButton' (Name=''); target element is 'MultiLineButton' (Name=''); target property is 'company' (type 'String')"

Comment: Added it to the first post.

Comment: and SystemModel has these dependency properties too? (with first letter capital)

Comment: Yes SystemModel has the same names.

Comment: is multilinebutton a usercontrol or custom control?

Answer (score 2):

1. not sure, maybe you should remove `DataType="SystemModel"` from DateTemplate.
2. Or try to use simple textbox(Binding id) as DataTemplate, see if there is still empty.
3. If above didn't get you any help, try Snoop(snoopwpf.codeplex.com) see what happended.

Comment: 1. Tried, but doesn't work
2. This works, the problem is that the usercontrol doesn't bind to the list item